# Using Cepstral Swift - Oss support after update to Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, oss

I use a Cepstral voice, with the swift commando.

```
swift "hello"
```

Some Ubuntu updates ago this didn't work anymore. The solution was to use an OSS wrapper (If I understand it well).

```
padsp "hello"
```

With the most recent update to Ubuntu 22.04 this also doesn't work anymore:

```
pw@pw-ubuntu:~$ padsp swift "hello"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/\15366LIB/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/\15366LIB/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
oss_audio: failed to open audio device /dev/dsp
```

Is there a way to make my cepstral voice work again?

The file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' does exist

This output might be of interest (I don't understand it myself...):

```
pw@pw-ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe libpulsedsp
[sudo] password for pw:
modprobe: FATAL: Module libpulsedsp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic
```

Ubuntu 22.04
pulseaudio 15.99.1

Comment: Is the package `libpulsedsp` installled?

Comment: @Jos Yes, libpulsedsp installed: 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1

Comment: What is the output of `echo $LD_PRELOAD`? I'm a bit suspicious of the string `/usr/\15366LIB/pulseaudio/`.

Comment: I suppose that should be `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio` but I'm not sure where it is to be changed.

Comment: @Jos Variable LD_PRELOAD is unset...

Comment: Can you `grep` the `/usr` folder for that string 15336LIB? Or perhaps `/home` as well? I'm pretty sure it is wrong and messing up your modules.

Comment: @ Jos ; I ran`sudo grep -ir 15366LIB /usr` and `sudo grep -ir 15366LIB /home/` with no result...

Comment: Different approach: does the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so` exist? If so, can you load it with `sudo modprobe libpulsedsp`? If you do `modprobe -l | grep pulse`, does the module show up, and if so, with what path name?

Comment: @ Jos 'modprobe -l' gives an error: 'modprobe: invalid option -- l'

Comment: @Jos The other output I've put in the (edited) question...